# Modifying String taken from database with input taken from textfield

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table in mysql database having only 2 column (Serial No and Statements)
In statements I have Statements like :

```
( My name is _ )
```

I have to replace _ from the word taken from jtextfield.
I tried to do using PreparedStatement

`(used ? instead _ )`

Suppose i typed Jack in jtextfield.
The Output was:

```
(My name is 'Jack' )
```

I dont want the inverted commas!
Help Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update `_` of `statement` in your database with the text typed in your text field.

You can use `UPDATE` query with `replace`

```
UPDATE demoTable SET statement = REPLACE(statement, '_', 'YourName');
```

If you have retrieved statement from database successfully and want to replace `_` with name in java program. You should use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method of `String` in java.

**FOR EXAMPLE**

```
String statement = "Hi, _";
String name = "Mike";
String yourString = statement.replace("_", name);
System.out.println(yourString);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Hi, Mike
```

Comment: I dont want to change values in table permanently, The table consists of fill in the blank questions.

Comment: whenever user types a word in textfield in java and clicks button.he get the preview of question ( _ replaced by the word he entered)